# How to save matching words from output of dmesg in a list

Tags: ubuntu, grep, dmesg

I am connecting USB-Serial devices to my device using different ports and serial-USB devices sometimes show up as 'ttyUSB0', sometimes 'ttyUSB1' or 'ttyUSB2'.

How can I write a script to extract all ttyUSB names from this command:

```
deviceNodes = "$(sudo dmesg tail | egrep -i 'ttyUSB')"
   echo "${deviceNodes}"

   for i in "${deviceNodes[@]}"
   do
    udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB1 | grep '{serial}' | head -n1
   done
```

and save it in a variable and loop over items in the list?

Here is the ouput of dmesg command:

```
[37606.832517] usb 2-1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[37664.565271] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[37695.844687] usb 2-1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[38017.111961] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[38490.802048] usb 2-1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[38776.225985] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[38778.317840] usb 2-1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[38874.027395] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[38876.631579] usb 2-1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[39040.443963] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[39796.942837] usb 2-1.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[39802.674018] usb 2-1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[40372.029798] ftdi_sio ttyUSB1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
[40372.156024] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[41642.886671] usb 2-1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Please add output of `sudo dmesg tail | egrep -i 'ttyUSB'` to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> deviceNodes = "$(sudo dmesg tail | egrep -i 'ttyUSB')"
```

That's a syntax error.  You can't have whitespace around the equals sign in a variable assignment.  See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#foo_.3D_bar

Furthermore, if you only want to iterate over the actual matches, you need to change the expression to only extract those.  Try this.

```
dmesg | grep -Eo 'ttyUSB[0-9]+' | sort -u |
while read devnode; do
    udevadm info -a -n /dev/"$devnode" | grep '{serial}' | head -n1
done
```

(On my system, `dmesg` runs without `sudo` just fine, and doesn't have a `tail` argument.)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it simply a matter of changing the following,

```
deviceNodes = "$(sudo dmesg tail | egrep -i 'ttyUSB')"
```

to this?

```
deviceNodes="$(cat temp | egrep -i 'ttyUSB' | sed 's/^.*tty/tty/' )"
```

'i' will obviously be the variable you need to iterate over.

Test was the following.

```
echo "[37664.565271] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0" | sed 's/^.*tty/tty/'
ttyUSB0
```